# user inputs separated with spaces and line breaks

Tags: java

i have generated a pace of code that gets 4 inputs and calculates the square roots of all of them.

```
    int i;
    System.out.print("print numbers here:");
    int[] arr = new int[4];
    Scanner in =  new Scanner(System.in);
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
        arr[i] = in.nextInt();
    }
    for (i = arr.length; i > 0; --i){
        double s =Math.sqrt(arr[i-1]);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

here is the code from main method but one important part that i still need to add is to get user inputs with spaces and line breaks. So, for instance

```
1427  0   

   876652098643267843 
5276538
```

1427 is first num, 0 the second and etc.. i am new to java and programming and i don't have any idea please help if you can. 
thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you explain your problem clearly? are you inputting all 4 numbers in single row? or 4 lines?

Comment: there are different lines and pleas mention that 2 line is empty

Comment: How are you inputting those numbers? Because if you press enter, the results are produced. Are you doing copy and paste, for I don't think a scanner deals with copy and paste. See here:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) call with [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--). This will retrieve the next word, with whitespace characters as seperators (newlines and spaces). This will allow for any number of spaces, empty lines etc.

**Example**:

```
System.out.print("print numbers here:");
int[] arr = new int[4];
Scanner in =  new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    int num;
    try {
        num = Integer.parseInt(in.next()); // get input
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // invalid number
    }
    arr[i] = num;
}
for (int i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {
    double s = Math.sqrt(arr[i-1]);
    System.out.println(s);
} // this is printing the square roots in reverse order, you may want to change
// that to avoid confusion
```

Comment: thanks this really works though i don't get the whole point yet i will explore it now. Think you again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the answer by white space characters (spaces and line breaks), try using the .split function present in Java. In your case, you would take the input received from the user as a String, then do this:

```
String[] inputVariables = string.split("\\s");
```

(note that \s represents all white space characters and "string" is your input received)
Now you have a String array of the input received from the user. Then you can use Integer.parseInt on each String to convert them from Strings to ints, and you now have your four integers ready to square-rootify.

Comment: @Garik Line breaks are considered whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
   try{
      String []nos = in.nextLine().split("\\s+");
      if(nos.length > 0)
      {
          for(String no:nos)
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(no);  
      }else{
          arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
      }
   }catch(Exception e){
      i--;
   }
}
```

Comment: what if there are several inputs in one line?

Comment: @Garik that is handle by the for loop